# What was the significance of two different shoes worn in Peaceful Warrior?

Tags: plot-explanation, analysis, peaceful-warrior

Dan Millman, in his dreams in *Peaceful Warrior*, sees a man wearing two different shoes collecting the broken bones. So what exactly is meant by showing the shoes of different color?

Even at one instance Dan Millman's eyeballs also change color and both eyeballs were of different color.

So what exactly is the significance of different color?

Answer (score 2):

Dreaming about two different shoes represents **two different paths**. Where there can be two different methods of living and you are not sure of which one to follow. In the movie, Dan has **two choices** which he realizes further. That is either to live for **temporary things** like gymnastics training, schoolwork, women and gold or to **live in the present moment**.